Installing 24.04 on workstation using a bootable Ubuntu USB resulted in UEFI problems and "Drive not found" BIOS message
I have a Dell Latitude E5530 with 6 GB of RAM and a 1 TB hard drive. When trying to install Ubuntu 22.xx, I encountered a boot issue, which I didn't experience with previous Ubuntu versions. I used the same USB drive to successfully install the operating system on an older HP laptop without any boot problems, however on the Dell the only way I've been able to resolve the issue is by running the installer again and selecting the "Install side by side" (dual boot) option. Afterwards I get a Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\ = Not Found  error message, but I can still boot into Ubuntu by choosing it from the boot selection menu.
I have read several similar questions online, and many suggest deleting or adding partitions which I don't want to do. Could there be a simple fix without having to modify partitions?
In order to boot from the USB drive I have to change the boot order in the BIOS settings, resulting in a non-UEFI configuration on boot.

Your problem is that you need to boot the Ubuntu installation USB in UEFI mode, but it will only let you boot it in BIOS mode. If Secure Boot is turned off in the UEFI setup utility it would possibly let you boot from a bootable USB in UEFI mode. Secure Boot is a security feature that restricts the system to boot only trusted, signed operating systems. By turning it off you're allowing the system to boot from unsigned media like a bootable Ubuntu USB.
Once you've successfully installed Ubuntu, remember to re-enable Secure Boot to maintain system security.

Follow these steps to access the Secure Boot option on a Dell Latitude E5530 computer.

Enter UEFI setup utility.

Turn on your Dell Latitude E5530.
As soon as the Dell logo appears press F2 repeatedly to open the UEFI setup utility. Some Dell computers have a boot menu which can be accessed by pressing the F12 key.


Navigate to the Secure Boot option.

In the UEFI setup utility use the arrow keys to navigate to the Boot tab.
Look for the Secure Boot option which is usually under the Boot tab on Dell systems.


Disable Secure Boot.

Use the arrow keys to select Secure Boot, then press Enter.
You'll see an option to enable or disable it.


Press F10 save changes and exit.



This Dell E5530 does not have a secure boot option. I assume none exists.

Maybe the Dell E5530 has a boot menu key (F12). You could try pressing F12 at boot time. I added this to my answer.

As you can currently boot into the Ubuntu all you need to do is to re-install grub with an added flag: -
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX


If you can't boot into Ubuntu then re-install grub from the install media following instructions in the following link: -
https://www.shellhacks.com/reinstall-grub-from-live-usb-uefi-lvm/
But with a slight alteration.
grub-install /dev/sdX should be modified to
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX

On the disk with the UEFI partition on it.

Being a noob I don't have the courage to follow instructions so I installed yet another OS. (Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon) which comes with a boot repair utility.
